# find rails db object to run a task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to run a task but running into an error `` NoMethodError: undefined method `queue' for #<Extension:0x00564c287c27c8>' for 2:Fixnum `` in trying to find the db object. I have two tables in my db that I need to work with for this task. `queues` and `extensions`
From `queues` I need the `id` and the `name`

```
task :add_queue_dialplan => :environment  do
  ids = Queue.all.ids
  queue = Queue.find_by_id(ids)


  Extension.all.each do |exten_conf|
    puts "#{exten_conf.queue.id} exten_conf:  #{exten_conf.tenant_id}"
    exten_conf.update_columns(category: "queue-#{queue.id}")
    exten_conf.update_columns(var_name: "exten")
    exten_conf.update_columns(var_val: "=> s,1,Macro#{queue.name})")
  end
end
```

Comment: Please show your DB schema. And `Extension` model code.

Comment: Can you show your model? It looks like you haven't setup your associations properly on the Extension model if it's not picking up the Queue. Does the extension belong_to the Queue?

Comment: It seems the first two lines inside the task just assign an array of all Queue models to the queue variable. So simpler is just queue=Queue.all. But now down in the block you use queue.id and queue.name, but the variable queue doesn't have such methods, it's an array of models. I'm guessing that the first two lines inside the task should be returning a single Queue model, but they're not, this is the problem.

Comment: It's unclear why `queue` is calculated this 'interesting' way, but `find_by_id` will return first found record @LesNightingill. And it should have `id` and `name` value (assuming they are part of `queue`)

Comment: Oh yes, you're right @Olkin, my mistake.